# Change wordpress default upload path to another domain

Tags: images, uploads

I have a domain, for example [tarikhema.org](http://tarikhema.org). I want to change WordPress default upload patch folder to another domain for example dtours.net. How can I do this?

My default folder is `tarikhema.org/images/....`
I want this: `dtours.net/images/...`.

[image: Uploads Settings]

Comment: You can using [WP Offload S3](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/) or [W3 Total Cache](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-with-wordpress). Both examples are using AWS S3, there are probably other ways. But it's impossible to suggest anything without knowing how your domains are set up, if you're willing to use AWS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. WordPress can store files only in its own uploads folder (or at least in the same root where the WordPress is installed. You can't upload files to remote website (different domain).

What you can do is to add the second domain as an alias to your main domain, and in that case, all URL's from the main domain will match the alias domain too.

Comment: You can (see my comment on the question)

Comment: As I see it, that was not the question. And, offloading files to CDN is not the same as changing domain, considering how complicated would be to properly set domain mapping with third-party CDN, especially if SSL needs to be used.

Comment: What if I have other domain on the same server than is it possible?

Comment: In general, WordPress can work within own folder only. It is possible to setup another website, and have it share locations with other website, but that is not easy to do, and it depends on your setup.

Comment: It's complicated and I wouldn't attempt it because I don't think it would be worth the effort, but it's possible.  Technically everything is possible if you're willing to put in the time and effort.
I suspect what you'd need to do is write a secondary process that moves the images to a different domain and then you update their location in the database.  Quick test, put a file on different domain, manually go into the DB with phpMyAdmin and change the URL of the attachment.

Comment: I just tested it, moved a file that is an attachment to another server, then went to the phpMyAdmin and changed the URL in the posts table GUID for that attachment and it still works.  So yeah, it'd be super tricky, probably not worth the effort when a CDN would be far simpler, but it is possible.